# Ag Grid getModel

Tags: filter, ag-grid, setstate, ag-grid-react

I have a React project with **rowModelType = 'serverSide'**.
I also have a custom component for filtering.
And I have an external button that should clear this filter
When I click on the button the function is triggered - **gridApi.setFilterModel(null)**;
Next, the setModel function is called in the component
Where
assigned to **this.setState({checkedFilters: []})**
Next, the **gridApi.getFilterModel()** method is called;
Next, the **getModel()** method is called where **this.state.checkedFilters** is equal to the old value i.e. **[1,2]**
Maybe somebody will prompt in what a problem of obtaining of old value?

```
**Component state =  
this.state = {
checkedFilters: [1,2]
};**
```